# Type error in explicitly typed binding (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing a very simple function which transforms a string by replacing a certain combinations of characters into another. (e.g. "ab" to "a")
I am a noob in Haskell, and I get error: "Type error in explicitly typed binding"

Could you please tell me what is the problem?
Code:

```
transform :: String -> String
transform [] = []
transform [x] = x
transform (x:y:xs)
        | x == "a" && y == "b" = "a" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == "b" && y == "a" = "b" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == "b" && y == "b" = "a" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == "a" && y == "a" = "aaa" ++ (transform xs)
```

Thank you!

Comment: @zakyggaps So I have to change it to transform [x] = [x]?
I did, and I get another error: "Type error in application"

Comment: @zakyggaps Sorry, I figured that this is an easy problem and the error can be easily spotted by someone who knows Haskell well.

Comment: So sarcastic:) I sincerely recommend some more feature-rich haskell implementation and editor like those mentioned in [this page](http://achernyak.me/universal-haskell-dev-enviornment) than the one you currently have. It will be great help when no one who knows Haskell well is in reach. I'm sorry if I've been offensive or off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the final `transform` pattern, you are using string literals for "a" and "b" when they should be characters.

```haskell
transform :: String -> String
transform [] = []
transform [x] = [x]
transform (x:y:xs)
        | x == 'a' && y == 'b' = "a" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == 'b' && y == 'a' = "b" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == 'b' && y == 'b' = "a" ++ (transform xs)
        | x == 'a' && y == 'a' = "aaa" ++ (transform xs)
```

Also, there was a bug in the second transform definition, where you needed to wrap `x` in brackets because it was returning a list of characters.

(You may also want to have a final pattern match to handle any other input, since you'll get a non-exhaustive error if you run this against a string like "zzz")